# Datatables issue with MongoID , Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid

I am using a datatables gem ( https://github.com/potatosalad/mongoid-data_table ) which supports MongoID,
But exception is raising from following code

```
format.json do
    render :json => Game.to_data_table(self)
end

Game.to_data_table(self)


INTERNAL ERROR!!! undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xb38d7bc>
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.2.5/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:369:in `method_missing'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/bundler/gems/mongoid-data_table-23283e37979c/lib/mongoid/data_table/proxy.rb:47:in `collection'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/bundler/gems/mongoid-data_table-23283e37979c/lib/mongoid/data_table/proxy.rb:263:in `method_missing'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/commands/eval.rb:47:in `block in execute'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/commands/eval.rb:19:in `run_with_binding'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/commands/eval.rb:46:in `execute'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:280:in `one_cmd'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:261:in `block (2 levels) in process_commands'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:260:in `each'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:260:in `block in process_commands'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:253:in `catch'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:253:in `process_commands'
    /home/naveed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:173:in `at_line'
    (eval):5:in `block in at_line'
    <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    (eval):3:in `at_line'
```

These are my mongo gems

```
gem 'mongo'
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.1"
gem 'bson', '= 1.4.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '= 1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that at one point there was a problem with the `bson 1.4.0` gem and they actually revoked it and then put a new one back out.  Perhaps try upgrading `bson` and `bson_ext` gems.  You can remove the `mongo` gem from the Gemfile, as it is a dependency for `mongoid`.  Likewise, you can remove the `bson` gem from your Gemfile since it is a dependency for `mongo` (which is a dependency for `mongoid`).  Also remove the version specification for the `bson_ext` gem.  Then do `bundle update bson` and `bundle update bson_ext`.  See if that fixes it.